# NoReverseMatch at /resetpassword/ in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, passwords, reset

I´m getting this error during Reset Password. I have a login page whith the link to reset forgotten password, it shows correctly the templates, but if I write the mail to send the reset link, it shows this error:

**localhost/resesetpassword**

```
NoReverseMatch at /resetpassword/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword      arguments '{'token': '42e-71994a9bf9d36c22eb95', 'uidb64': b'MQ'}' not found. 0   pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost/resetpassword/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'token': '42e-71994a9bf9d36c22eb95', 'uidb64': b'MQ'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-   packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 496
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['c:\\labsoft',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\psycopg2-2.6-py3.4-win-amd64.egg',
'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python34\\lib',
'C:\\Python34',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
 Server time:   Dom, 7 Jun 2015 21:46:55 -0500
```

**Error during template rendering**

```
     In template C:\Python34\lib\site-  packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\registration\password_reset_email.html, error at line 6


1   {% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
2   {% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}
3   
4   {% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
5   {% block reset_link %}
6   
  {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}
  {% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}



7   {% endblock %}
8   {% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}
9   
10  {% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}
11  
12  {% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}
13  
14  {% endautoescape %}
15
```

**It shows this code in red:**

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

**I think the error can be the protocol and domain parameters, but I don't know how fix it. Thanks a lot!!!**

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from .views import Buscar_view

urlpatterns = patterns('melomanos.views',
                   url(r'^$','trabajos_all_view',name='url_index'),
                    url(r'^register/$','register_view',name='vista_registro'),
                   url(r'^login/$','login_view',name='vista_login'),
                   url(r'^logout/$','logout_view',name='vista_logout'),
                   url(r'^perfil/$','registro_view',name='vista_perfil'),
                   url(r'^publicar/$','trabajomusical_view', name='vista_publicar'),
                   url(r'^trabajos/$','trabajos_view',name='vista_trabajos'),
                   url(r'^trabajo/(?P<id_trabajo>.*)/$','solo_trabajo_view', name='vista_trabajo'),
                   url(r'^buscar/$',Buscar_view.as_view(),name='vista_buscar'),
                   )

 urlpatterns += patterns('',
                   url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='password_reset_done'),
                   url(r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name="reset_password"),
                   url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
                   url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete',{'template_name' : 'registration/password_reset.html',  'post_reset_redirect': '/logout/' }),
                   )
```

Comment: Sharing your urls.py will be helpful to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your regex for the token parameter is matching a single or multiples commas.

You can use `<token>.+` for match any character.

Also your pattern is looking for a `-` between the `uidb64` and `token`, and this line

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

is passing both parameters without the `-`.

You need just to alter the url line as folow:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Comment: This solution works for me in a part, the mail was sent and i have received it, but the link stills showing me an error: `NoReverseMatch at /reset/MQ-42e-71994a9bf9d36c22eb95/
Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`     -------   `Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/reset/MQ-42e-71994a9bf9d36c22eb95/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete. Your url for password reset done is missing the name param, use this instead: `url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete',{'template_name' : 'registration/password_reset.html',  'post_reset_redirect': '/logout/' }, name='password_reset_complete')`

Comment: I still have this error:      `TypeError at /reset/MQ-42e-71994a9bf9d36c22eb95/
password_reset_complete() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/reset/MQ-42e-71994a9bf9d36c22eb95/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
password_reset_complete() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response, line 132
    ------     ` response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)`

Comment: I have this error: `Exception Value: 
password_reset_complete() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'` thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Can we go to the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79914/discussion-between-sgmart-and-jairo-betancourt).

Answer (score 0):

add `password_reset_confirm` to url name

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
                   url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='password_reset_done'),
                   url(r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name="reset_password"),
                   url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),
                   url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete',{'template_name' : 'registration/password_reset.html',  'post_reset_redirect': '/logout/' }),
                   )
```